# Convert text file with key=value pair to specific json format in jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have a text file with  following values in 
input.txt

```
key1=value1\r
key2=value2
key3=value3\r
key4=value4
```

need the jq rexpression to convert it to  below json format  by removing "\r" also

output.json

```
{
"Environment": {
    "Variables": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4"
    }
}
```

}

I have tried the below expression and getting the

```
jq -Rs [ split("\n")[] | select(length > 0) | split("=") | {(.[0]): .[1]} ]
```

and getting the below output

```
[
  {
   "key1ey1": "Value1\r"
  },
  {
   "key2": "value2"
  },
  {
   "key3": "value3\r"
  },
  {
   "key4": "value4"
  }

]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -sR '{"Environment":
            {"Variables": [split("\n")[:-1][] | rtrimstr("\\r") 
                             | split("=") | {(.[0]): .[1]}
                          ]  | add
            }
        }' input.txt
```

The output:

```
{
  "Environment": {
    "Variables": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3",
      "key4": "value4"
    }
  }
}
```

### Caveat

This solution assumes `=` does not appear in the "value" section of the input strings.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach allows `=` to appear in the value portion of the `key=value` strings:

Invocation: jq -n -R -f program.jq input.txt

program.jq:

```
[inputs | sub("\\\\r$";"") | capture("^(?<key>[^=]*)=(?<value>.*)")]
| from_entries
| {Environment: { Variables: .}}
```

Comment: Removed the dupe in the other que. You can answer there if you want