# Converting text file in key value format to a JSON object

Tags: json, jq

I have a .env file with this content:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://example.com.br
```

And I need to transform in something like this:

```
"environment": [
    {
        "name": "APP_ENV",
        "value": "local"
    },
    {
        "name": "APP_DEBUG",
        "value": "true"
    },
    {
        "name": "APP_URL",
        "value": "http://example.com.br"
    }
]
```

I try to transform the file into a bash array, then convert to json with jq, but without success.
Can anybody give a tip?

Comment: You need to look at [Convert text file with key=value pair to specific json format in `jq`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51115902/5291015)

Comment: @Inian Thanks for the suggestion, I made a simple adaptation and it's working. 
```jq -sR '{"Environment": [ split("\n")[:-1][] | rtrimstr("\\r") | split("=") | {name:.[0],value:.[1]}]}' env```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adapted from [Convert text file with key=value pair to specific json format in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51115902/5291015)

```
jq -sR '{"Environment": [ split("\n")[:-1][] | rtrimstr("\\r") | split("=") | {name:.[0],value:.[1]}]}' env
```

Answer (score 0):

```
env $(cat .env) jq -n '$ENV | with_entries(select(.key | index("APP_") == 0))'
```

The above command runs `jq` in an environment modified according to the `.env` file and then selects the subset of the environment where variable names start with `APP_`.

The jq manual has explanation about `$ENV`, `with_entries`, `select`, and `index` functions which I used.

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

A smaller solution:

```
env -i $(cat .env) $(which jq) -n '$ENV'
```

The `env -i` command runs `jq` in an environment which is otherwise empty except for the values in `.env`. `jq` then only dumps the environment. This method removes restrictions on prefixes to start in some particular way.

`$(which jq)` places the absolute path of `jq` binary in command, which is necessary because there is no `PATH` environment variable where it can look for programs. Remember that `env -i` starts with an empty environment.

Here the running of `jq` requires no input text. So I used `jq -n` which assumes the input to be `null`.

Comment: great solution although, if your .env file values are wrapped in double quotes

`TESTING="123"
FOO="BAR"`

then the output values include the double quotes `{
  "TESTING": "\"123\"",
  "FOO": "\"BAR\""
}` . any idea have the value omit the wrapping double quotes?